# Can't get correct exit message to display when authentication fails

Tags: php

Look at the second Exit message on this page, 'Your credentials are invalid'.

For some reason, I can't get this message to display.

The first exit message does display properly, but that message ends up getting shown all the time, rather than the more custom second Exit message.

How can I get this second message to display?

```
<?php
require_once('connectvars.php');
?>

<?php

//if username and password not entered, show popup

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Databasename"');
    //if they click cancel
    exit('Must enter credentials to continue. '); //this works just fine
}

//grab the user entered login data
$user_username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$user_password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

//look up the username and password in the database
$query= "SELECT user_id, username 
        FROM table_name 
        WHERE username = '$user_username' 
        AND " . "password = SHA('$user_password')";
$data= mysqli_query($dbc, $query);


if (mysqli_num_rows($data) ==1) {
    //the login is okay so set the user id and username variables
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $username = $row['username'];

    echo 'You are logged in as ' . $username ; //this all works
}


//here is where my problems begin
else {
        //credentials were wrong
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Databasename"');
    //if they click cancel here, how come the text below isn't showing? Currently it's like the code jumps back up to the first header exit message. 
    exit('Your credentials are invalid');
}
?>
```

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment and your code do not match.

```
//if username and password not entered, show popup

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
```

The code reads if either `PHP_AUTH_USER`  **or** `PHP_AUTH_PW` is not set then ...

Which means when you leave either username or password blank, the condition will be true.

Easy fix, change `||` to `&&`

Since `isset()` will return `true` even when the value is blank, just check whether the value is not blank.

```
if (!$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] && !$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, that’s just a typo in my comment and is unrelated to the issue I’m having.

Comment: @JDH I also suggest you check whether the value is not blank.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem. The issue is the second Exit message doesn't display. I intend this to work in a way that if user clicks "Cancel" from that second popup box, then they get the custom Exit message (the second Exit message shown on the page). However, it seems that no matter what I do, the first Exit message is always shown. I'm starting to think maybe it's b/c the book I am reading with this example is 10 years old and maybe what I am trying to do simply will no longer work? For example, should I even be calling headers this far down on the page?